# Take back a flag

Tags: support, flagging

I think I just have to count on moderation to fix my last flag which was a mistake, but is there a way I'm not seeing to take back a flag before it gets moderated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the flag link on the post you flagged to open the flag dialog. Without selecting any flag type, the blue button used to flag a post is now a Retract Flag button, which you can click to retract your flag.

Comment: ok... I don't see it now, but it was already moderated, so I think I missed my window.

Comment: ah... no (I just flagged your answer to test... sorry) it doesn't seem to appear if you flag an answer, just a question.

Comment: there goes my helpful flag ratio :D

Comment: @dwightk Can definitely do it on answers too, I’ve checked my flag history and have retracted on questions and answers. Which flag type have you raised?

Comment: maybe it doesn't work on "not an answer" that was the one I selected on your answer and it didn't let me take it back.

Comment: @dwightk, as a non-moderator I just flagged this as not an answer and was able to retract straight away. I've also done it fairly recently on the main site when someone posted a NAA and then realized their mistake, found a solution and change it to an actual answer.

Comment: weird.. I definitely saw the way to take it back on this question, but not on this answer.